# I need to change date part of DateTime variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, datetime

I'm having a problem with one of my variables.
I have 2 variables, `:starts_on` and `:ends_on` . Both are of type DateTime. `:starts_on` gets assigned a date and a time in the form, however `:ends_on` only gets assigned time from the form. Unfortunately, the date part becomes "2000-01-01", which is not right. I would like to assign date from `:starts_on` variable, then user can change time part in the form. So far it doesn't work. My code:

in app/views/courses/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @course do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :starts_on, "Date:" %>
  <%= f.date_select :starts_on %>

  <%= f.label :starts_on, "Time:" %>
  <%= f.time_select :starts_on, :ignore_date => true %>

  <%= f.time_select :ends_on, :ignore_date => true %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

in app/controllers/courses_controller.rb (I'm only showing `edit` action, but `new` is the same idea)

```
def edit
  @course = Course.find(params[:id])
  @course.ends_on = @course.starts_on
end
```

So, I attempted putting the code there to make `ends_on` equal `starts_on` and then in the form the user would change the time part of it. However this doesn't work and the date ends up being "2000-01-01" for all of them (time part is correct). If I look up the value of `ends_on` in the form - it is correct, but doesn't save correctly. Please help?

**Edit / Solution:**

I figured it out.
I tried changing in controller's `update` action - didn't work. I tried making hidden `date_select` and in the end what worked was:

```
<div style="display: none;">
  <%= f.date_select :ends_on %>
</div>
```

This is quite frustrating that THAT is the only thing that works. It appears that there MUST be `<%= f.date_select :ends_on %>` in order for it to add a date to the god damn variable. You can't even go without `=` (the equal sign). Very frustrating.
Thank you for comments and answers, it was all helpful.

I feel that this problem could have better solutions, so this question might be useful in the future to others.

Comment: You'll need to handle that in the update method, not edit. In update set the date portion of `@course.ends_on` based on the date portion of `@course.starts_on` after loading the parameters. (Don't just set `@course.ends_on = @course.starts_on` as that will wipe out the time portion.)

Comment: How can I set just the date portion? I tried using `.change` method (like `@course.ends_on.change(year: @course.starts_on.year, month: .., day: ..)`, which didn't work because it says `nilClass`

Comment: Did your code look like `@course.ends_on = @course.ends_on.change(year: @course.starts_on.year, month: @course.starts_on.month, day: @course.starts_on.day)`? Note that `change` doesn't actually modify the immutable `DateTime` object, it just returns an an object that is what you want. If so what was the exact error message?

Comment: Hmm... It doesn't show an error now, but also doesn't change the date. I also tried `@course.update_attributes!(:ends_on => @course.ends_on.change(.....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding a hidden `<%= f.date_select :ends_on %>`? I'm assuming you are only concerned with preventing the user from having to select the same date, so you can have this tag in the form but hide it with css in the html_options hash.

Comment: Since this is pretty much what I did, I'm accepting this answer. Thank you for your help.